# DAX - RankX only for rows that exist in another table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to rank a list of items based on their product views. I only want to rank items if they exist in another related table "Stock Product Views".

I have written this DAX formula, however it returns "1" for all rows in the "dim Product" table.

> Ranking_Views_Desc =
>
> RANKX (
> FILTER( 'dim Product', 'dim Product'[Item ID] IN VALUES('Stock Product Views'[ItemID])),
> [# Product Views]
> ,,
> DESC,
> DENSE )

How can I write a DAX calculation that ranks all the "item ID" values in "dim Product" based on their product views? The ranking calculation should also ignore any filters from outside the query (i.e. slicers).

Comment: try this
Ranking_Views_Desc =
RANKX (
FILTER (
ALL('dim Product'[Item ID]),
'dim Product'[Item ID] IN VALUES('Stock Product Views'[ItemID])
),
[# Product Views],
,
DESC,
DENSE
)

Comment: @Sparsh Jain Bizarrely that gives a ranking of 1-9 but its not clear what is causing each product to be assigned its rank. Do you know why? Of the thousands of items in "dim Product", I'm only expecting 287 to be ranked (i.e. 287 items from "dim Product" exist in "Stock Product Views".